# How to store passwords in a desktop application that needs to know login credentials without user interaction

Tags: java, encryption

I realize this topic has been covered (briefly) in the question: [How to store database credentials in a desktop application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812609/how-to-store-database-credentials-in-a-desktop-application)

but that was asked, and subsequently answered over a year ago. I have a desktop application that needs to contact a database, but using permissions that the user *has no idea about*. If it were a case of someone interacting and entering credentials, it'd be much simpler to secure. So the question is this: For a desktop application that needs to know passwords IN CODE without any user interaction at all, what is the **best** way to accomplish this, using modern tools. I realize nothing will be perfectly secure, since the encryption/decryption must live somewhere in the code for someone clever enough to find, but surely some methods make it more of a pain than others to accomplish that task?

Comment: Since there is no good solution (except expensive security hardware) for storing the password in a secure way you can at least make sure that it can be changed easily.